# How to validate column in different list

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, validation

I have two lists in SharePoint 2013. List1 and List2. List1 has two fields(Name and EmployeeID). In list2 user enter ID # manually but we need to validate against list1 ID# if it matches I need to create a 2nd validation for the name based on ID. If it doesn't match they can't submit the form. Any Idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your own JavaScript code in a new `PreSaveAction` function on the Form

There you read your other list, do your checks and return a true value when all is fine

https://www.google.nl/search?q=presaveaction

Comment: Hey Danny Did you look at ? I'm here in List2 I just want to validate List1 field ? share your idea . Tnx

Comment: No I never read questions. On Form #2 you need to add JavaScript that reads List1 , you could display all of List1 IN Form2, that saves you the reading, but you still have to write the ``PreSaveAction``